# Setup DNS - different mailservers for different accounts on same domain

Tags: domain-name-system, email

How to setup DNS so you can use multiple mail servers with both different mail accounts on them?

Reason I ask is because I have gone from a mail server from a website-provider to a paid solution. Not all accounts need the extra functionalities the paid provider provides. So I would like to have some email-accounts on my new paid provider and some on the old mailserver of my website provider.

Is this possible? Or is it only possible to have multiple mail-servers as fallback?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do this on a dns level since it only knows hostnames. It doesn't know anything about a domain. You would have to set this up on your email server and forward the email coming into the account to the other provider.